# MySQL Sorting on two columns with UNION

Tags: mysql, sorting, union

I have a couple of tables that I'd like to combine into one list. I have limited knowledge of what I can do with MySQL and already hit the fact that UNION needs to have the same amount of columns...

One table has data like the following:

| batch_no |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 9 |
| 10 |
| 12 |

The other has

| batch_no | subbatch_no |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 1 |
| 7 | 2 |
| 7 | 3 |
| 8 | 1 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 11 | 1 |
| 11 | 2 |

I basically want to be able to have a output that displays like this:

| batch_no |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7-1 |
| 7-2 |
| 7-3 |
| 8-1 |
| 8-2 |
| 9 |
| 10 |
| 11-1 |
| 11-2 |
| 12 |

I've had various attempts but the following is the best I came up with but obviously is sorting incorrectly...

```
SELECT batch_no FROM batch 
UNION
SELECT CONCAT(batch_no,'-',subbatch_no) FROM subbatch 
ORDER BY batch_no DESC
```

With this the order is seemingly being done as if it were text because I have put the hyphen in, stumped as to how to do this.

Comment: UNION remove duplicates from each table if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the ordering on the original union, adding an extra `subbatch_no` column to the `batch` subquery. Then order these together by two columns in the main query, where you can also concatenate them with the `-` separator.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-', batch_no, subbatch_no) AS combined_batch_no
FROM (
    SELECT batch_no, NULL AS subbatch_no
    FROM batch
    UNION
    SELECT batch_no, subbatch_no
    FROM subbatch
) AS sub1 
ORDER by batch_no, subbatch_no
```

Answer (score 1):

it is actually quite easy sorting apha numrical qith your data

> ```
> SELECT CAST(batch_no as char) batchno FROM batch 
> UNION 
> SELECT CONCAT(batch_no,'-',subbatch_no) FROM subbatch 
> ORDER BY batchno+0 ASC
> ```
>
> ```
> | batchno |
> | :------ |
> | 1       |
> | 2       |
> | 3       |
> | 4       |
> | 5       |
> | 6       |
> | 7-1     |
> | 7-2     |
> | 7-3     |
> | 8-1     |
> | 8-2     |
> | 9       |
> | 10      |
> | 11-1    |
> | 11-2    |
> | 12      |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0e69e3d828efb67dff9f8e7bf1e4cc00)*

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT_WS('-',batch_no,subbatch_no) from (
  SELECT batch_no,null subbatch_no FROM batch 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT batch_no,subbatch_no FROM subbatch 
) A
ORDER BY batch_no,subbatch_no
```

Comment: that will not give the result

Comment: This only applies `ORDER BY` to the second query. It doesn't order the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT batch_no, NULL as subbatch_no FROM tab1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM tab2
)
SELECT CONCAT_WS('-' , batch_no, subbatch_no) AS batch_no
FROM cte
ORDER BY cte.batch_no, cte.subbatch_no
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6M76mLgu3ybbM7CmmFKA73/0).